# What does legend mean in line chart with x axis as date and y axis as sales measure?

Tags: powerbi

I have a line chart with x axis as year week.

Y axis is sales measure.

What does legend mean for this chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drag another field to the legend well, it will create a separate line (series) for each one. e.g. you could drag product into the legend field well and it will give you one line per product.

Comment: If I add 2 measures to the y axis then it doesn't allow me to use legend. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes - that means you are manually adding series yourself rather than using the legend well to split the line into different series.

Answer (score 1):

Legend is where you can put categories into it, such as Region/Department/Product/Salesperson. With legend you can obtain several lines, mostly used in comparison purpose.

Be aware that legend should only be column not measure.

Here i got an example for you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSWrE.png)

Comment: Can legend be used if y axis has 2 measures?

Comment: no you cannot. if you add more than one measure then measures name actually is the legend. in this circumstances you will need to calculate new measures combine with legend.

Comment: here i give you an example:

2 measures: [sales], [revenue]
legend: [product] containing A, B, C

then you need to calculate 6 measures:
[sales-A]=calculate([sales],'table'[product]="A")
[sales-B]=calculate([sales],'table'[product]="B")
[sales-C]=calculate([sales],'table'[product]="C")
[revenue-A]=calculate([sales],'table'[product]="A")
[revenue-B]=calculate([sales],'table'[product]="B")
[revenue-C]=calculate([sales],'table'[product]="C")

then add all 6 measures into Y axis without legend.